# Can't find the XPath of a button in frame

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, frame

I tried to enter this website: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

and click on this button:

[image]

Then, I tried to click on this button:

[image]

and finally, on this button:

[image]

I used this code:

```
 driver1 = webdriver.Firefox()
 driver1.get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")
 driver1.switch_to.frame(driver1.find_element_by_css_selector('#recaptcha-               
 demo > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > iframe:nth-child(1)'))
 driver1.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="recaptcha-checkbox-
 checkmark"]').click()
 time.sleep(4)
 driver1.switch_to.default_content()
 driver1.switch_to.frame(driver1.find_element_by_css_selector("body >      
 div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(4) > iframe:nth-child(1)"))
 driver1.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="recaptcha-audio-button"]').click()
 driver1.find_element_by_css_selector('.rc-audiochallenge-tdownload-link').click()
```

Unfortunately, it clicked only on the first and the second buttons, but not on the third. Why did this happen?
I checked and the second and third buttons are in the same frame, so it seems strange, maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: reCAPTCHA was created to prevent bots from bypassing it.

Comment: Oh dude its not true , as a prove i clicked on two button there ...

Comment: I will not help you, robot.

Answer (score 0):

Just add some wait before clicking on the download button as given below.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.rc-audiochallenge-tdownload-link')))  
element.click()
```

I have tried it and worked fine.